# AreEqual(new object(), new object())

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты

Имею необходимость сравнить объекты на тождественное равенство,
а именно надо чтобы `Assert.AreEqual(new object(), new object());` (использую MSTest) или его аналог считал что объекты одинаковы, ведь у них совпадает тип и оба не null, а полей или свойств для сравнения нет. **Сравнение по ссылке меня не интересует.**
FluentAssertions и Shouldly не считают `new object()` и `new object()` одинаковыми. А DeepEqual имеет баг и считает объекты одинаковыми даже независимо от типа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113465/discussion-on-question-by-max-cat-areequalnew-object-new-object).

Answer (score 1):

Извините но вы программируете и путатете не много педали. Ваше предположение или представление не верно о равенствах ссылочных типов данных. Любые ссылочные типы данных не стоит сравнивать на прямую ведь они содержат в себе ссылку на объект, а не объект.

```
object actual = new object(); object expected = actual;
Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected); //true сравниваются значения в переменных.

object actual = new object(); object expected = new object();
Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected); //false также сравниваются значения в переменных, но тут уже это различные объекты.
```

костыли предлагаемые вам по сути это перевод в значимую переменную чтоб можно было сравнить не прибегая методу `Equal`